# Is it possible in matlab to declare functions that will be accessible from other m files in a similar way as in c coding?

Tags: matlab, function, scope

I have an .m file which includes many functions. I want to be able to call some of these functions from other .m files. How can I do that in matlab? - I do not want to have to write each function in a separate .m file . I want a way to declare the functions that I want to access from other .m files, just as in c programming. Can I do that in matlab?

Comment: was going to answer, but I think the related question above should clarify your problem

Comment: Writing function handles is the way around this disastrous failure in Matlab's basic paradigm. If you have the option, consider switching to `R` or `SciPy` . (and I speak as one with considerable experience in both r and Matlab)